# EF 6 Add Where Clause To An Include With Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm going to try ask this question without posting all the objects in my model.  I have a somewhat complex query but only two objects are related to the problem.

I have a website used to run office football pools.  So my domain model has Team and TeamRecords

Here are the definitions.  I removed some irrelevant properties on the object.

```
public class Team
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Team ID
    /// </summary>
    public int TeamID { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Team Recordproperty
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<TeamRecord> TeamRecords { get; set; }
}

public class TeamRecord
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Team ID
    /// </summary>
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Team the record belongs to
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Team Team { get; set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// Season ID
    /// </summary>
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Season navigation property
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }

}
```

I configure the Team to TeamRecords relationship like this:

```
HasMany(t => t.TeamRecords).WithRequired(tr => tr.Team).HasForeignKey(tr=>new {tr.TeamID});
```

Then I try to run a query like this.  Basically when I select a team, I want to only select the teamrecord for the current season.  So I want to add a where clause to my Include method.  Ignore the other objects in the query.  They're probably self explanatory.

```
var picks = context.Picks.Where(p => ((p.Game.SeasonID == seasonID) && (p.Game.Week ==     week) && (p.PoolID == poolID) && (p.UserID == userID)))
                            .Include(p => p.Game).Include(p => p.Game.HomeTeam).Include(p => p.Game.VisitingTeam).Include(p => p.Pool)
                            .Include(p => p.Game.HomeTeam.TeamRecords.Where(tr=>tr.SeasonID == seasonID))
                            .Include(p => p.Game.VisitingTeam.TeamRecords.Where(tr=>tr.SeasonID == seasonID))
                            .Select(p => p);
```

When I execute that line of code, I get the following error

The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

How can I accomplish this type of filtering?  I've searched the internet and have not had any luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change it to a select statement that produces anonymous type, then execute the query and select the root object again.

You can try something like this.

```
var picks = context.Picks.Where(p => ((p.Game.SeasonID == seasonID) && (p.Game.Week == week) && (p.PoolID == poolID) && (p.UserID == userID)))
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Pick = p,
        Game = p.Game,
        HomeTeam = p.Game.HomeTeam,
        VisitingTeam = p.Game.VisitingTeam,
        HomeTeamRecords = p.Game.HomeTeam.TeamRecords.Where(tr => tr.SeasonID == seasonID),
        VisitingTeamRecords = p.Game.VisitingTeam.TeamRecords.Where(tr => tr.SeasonID == seasonID),
        Pool = p.Pool
    })
    .ToArray().Select(p => p.Pick).ToArray();
```

And they will automatically connected, `Pick` to `Game`, `Game` to `HomeTeam`, `Game` to `VisitingTeam`, `HomeTeam` to `TeamRecords`, `VisitingTeam` to `TeamRecords`, `Pick` to `Pool`.

Also known as *[relationship fix-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)*.

Comment: Nice answer - never thought of using this combination of relationship fixup and anonymous types before.

Comment: @LongboatHarry, but we need to include all the hierarchy to make it work, for example if we exclude this `HomeTeam = p.Game.HomeTeam,` from select clause, then the end result of any `Pick` will have null reference of `pick.Game.HomeTeam`

Comment: @YuliamChandra thanks great answer!  The query compiles and executes.  I'm running into a small problem though.  The query for HomeTeamRecords and VisitingTeamRecords doesn't seem to be executing with the rest of the query.  When I try to access those properties outside of the query I get an exception, even if I add ToList() after the Where(). Any idea why?

Comment: @jeff.eynon, should not add `ToList` before `Select` clause, what's the error ?

Comment: It's the cannot access a disposed context message.  It's the message you get when EF needs to load the entities but the associated context has been disposed, which is what is suggesting to me that the TeamRecords aren't being loaded with the rest of the query.

Comment: @jeff.eynon, I forgot to mention, since you have virtual keyword in the collection, the filter you have selected will simply be ignored, even using explicit loading like what Harry suggested, it will try to reload all the related objects, the solution would be, you need to remove the virtual or manually filter them in the memory

Comment: Isn't that a catch 22 then?  Virtual is required in a reference relationship and EF won't load anything for me when I reference the collection so there won't be anything in memory....

Comment: @jeff.eynon, lazy loading with virtual somehow disable relationship fix-up and explicit loading, when you access the collection, the db context has been disposed and lazy loading tries to load, virtual is not mandatory, it's used to enable lazy loading, without it the relationship still working

Comment: I'm late to the party, but relationship fix-up is not working for me. I've created a where clause with predicate "false", but all objects are still returned. What are the preconditions in order for this to work?

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework has [no direct support for filtering the `Include` extension method](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method).

A common alternative is to combine the `Query` and `Load` methods on a tracked entity to perform a [**filtered explicit load**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232). (Search for *Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities* on that linked article.)

Taking just your `Team` and `TeamRecords` entities, this would look something like this:

```
// Ensure lazy loading is turned off
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

// load the team
var team = context.Teams.Find(teamId);

// explicitly load the team records for the current season
context.Entry(team)
    .Collection(t => t.TeamRecords)
    .Query()
    .Where(r => r.SeasonId == currentSeasonId)
    .Load();
```

Comment: this is also working by manually loads the collection, this is called deferred loading, right?

Comment: Ive only heard it called `Explicit` loading. I only really ever use `Load` when in combination with `Query` on a collection navigation property, as per this example.

Comment: This is a neat solution for a single entity, but for multiple team records this wouldn't do (without *n* subsequent queries)